# Make all <li>s, when clicked, scroll to a single anchor?

Tags: jquery

I have around 30 `li` nodes. When each one is clicked, I would like the browser to gently scroll to the div `sliderbox`. (I don't wnt to use anchor tags)

So, something like this:

```
$("#boxcont li").click(function(event){
   // (Make stuff happen here)
)};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+scroll+to+element

Answer (score 2):

check ths out

```
$("#boxcont li").click(function(event){
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#sliderbox').offset().top }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'swing'});
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately... :(.....

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#boxcont li").click(function(event){
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#sliderbox').offset().top }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'swing'});
});

});

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: `document.location=document.location + "#anchorName";`
add `<a name="anchorName"></a>` in the location you wish to scroll to

Comment: Ok, what if I didn't want to add the anchor name in the a tags? - So they just have to click the li element itself?

Comment: It's fine, don't feel bad, appreciate your help!

Comment: this method is based on jumping to anchor according to it's name

Comment: it's too simple, is han't incorporated  "slide" animations plus, I don't want to use hash tags.